# Applying a range filter only for a particular field with specific value in SOLR

Tags: solr

I have data indexed into solr as with fields like :-

name:Apples weight:5kg
name:Grapes weight:2kg
name:papaya weight:7kg
name:Apples weight:3kg
name:Grapes weight:3kg

I want my results to be shown in such a way that all my results except Apples comes as usual results and after that the results for apples are shown at the end that too with weight range of 4-8 kg only.
i.e the results for apples are shown at the end that too with a particular weight range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll have to limit the documents you want to your criteria - i.e. you want all documents, except for those that are apples and outside of 4-8kg (this assumes that your weight field is an integer - if it isn't - make it an integer field so that you can do proper range searches):

```
q=(*:* NOT name:Apples) OR (name:Apples AND weight[4 TO 8])
```

Then you can apply a negative boost to Apples (which you do by boosting everything that doesn't match by a large factor):

```
bq=(*:* -name:Apples)^1000
```

Comment: I tried the same with fq instead of q and it worked still can't figure out why q didn't filter out the results as needed.
The bq however was very helpful

Comment: The behavior of `q` depends on which query parser is active. The old dismax parser does not support (most of) the lucene syntax.